# Google Classroom API | How to access the API without permanently activating the application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

there is a need to make a bot that will receive information from the class, but there is a problem:

- The problem is that in order to access the API and the class, you need to get a token that has a lifespan of exactly 1 hour. Is it possible to somehow get a permanent token, or a type of account that does not require constant activation of the application, but only for a token that has an unlimited lifetime?

I tried to do so - if the token is invalid, then by the recovery token (possibly Access) I received a new token for an hour, but all these tokens are not eternal.

Comment: As far as i recall google classroom is part of google workspace, you could use a service account as long as you can configure domain wide deliation.

Comment: But I can once give permission to connect the API or my application, and not repeat this operation again, do I need to somehow connect to the api classroom account?

Comment: It is not possible to get a permanent token, if your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.).

Comment: Refres token Does it have a lifetime or is it eternal?